# Determinant of the Identity Matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I have trouble proving that for all $n$, $\det(I_{n})=1$

$I_{n}$ is Identity Matrix $nxn$

I tried to use Inductive reasoning but without any progress

Comment: How do *you* define determinant of a matrix?

Comment: Hint: Leibniz rule

Comment: @Fakemistake, I didn't learn it. I should prove somehow with Inductive reasoning

Comment: @ovedpoovedpo Great, then how do **you** define determinant of a matrix??

Comment: @Joanpemo, $det|A|=a_{11}M_{11}-a_{12}M_{12}+a_{13}M_{13}-...+(-1)^{1+n}a_{1n}M_{1n}$ that's what do you mean?

Comment: @ovedpoovedpo Thank you. Then A simple inductive proof makes the trick. Look at the answers in a few minutes more.

Comment: But for $I_1$ you need some other definition.

Comment: @mvw It is usually assumed and/or defined that $\;\det(k)=k\;$ for any $\;1\times1\;$ matrix $\;(k)\;$

Comment: Sure, but why? My guess is that it is because it fits either the geometric view as oriented volume or the algebraic as alternating multi linear form.

Comment: @mvw Thank you. Yes, I think so but I think simply that if fits, as you say , the more basic, elementary geometric view, only expanded a little to allow one dimensional volumes (i.e., length of vector) to be negative as well. I'm not sure that getting into multilinear alternating forms would give much of an insight here, in particular taking into account the asker's definition of determinant, which is the usual one in sciences outside physics and mathematics or in engeerings.

Answer (score 5):

For $\;n=1\;$ we clearly have $\;\det (1)=1\;$ , and even directly for $\;n=2\;$  :

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=1\cdot\det(1)=1$$

Now, take $\;I_n\;$ and develop with respect the first row (or the first column, it is exactly the same), then you get:

$$\det I_n=1\cdot \det I_{n-1}\stackrel{\text{inductive hypotesis}}=1\cdot1=1$$